# FacebookOAuth exception

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am new to Facebook. I am developing an app to post to news feed on my facebook page.

First I authenticate and once I authenticate, I use FacebookClient object to get facebook id as well as name. This is working fine.

I have button click event which does post to news feed. and it is returning the following exception.

{"(OAuthException) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}

I am following the sample code from http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

-> Post Publish

Where can i set in the facebook to allow the application to post?

thanks

Venkat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take five minutes and get familiar with: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins

Specifically with:

```
  <fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins">
     Login with Facebook
  </fb:login-button>
```

and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Hint: publish_stream